# How to use shared project in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have project structure like this using node express of javascript

- Shared
- - Models
- - Helpers
- - Utils
- API
- Socket

I have some shared logic in API and Socket which I wanted to share in Shared poject, but sure the best approach.

Also, in the code how do I use the Models, Helps and Utils .

The should should work with npm, package.json, nodemon and docker.

Please suggest.

I have tried this in the app project

"shared" : "file:../shared"

but it did not work.

Comment: You can just `require()` things from higher up folders